# Connection String Access for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

Have an asp.net project (4.0), and trying to figure out the best way to access the connection string.

I have 2 connection strings in web.config file, one for prod and other for test.  There are many aspx pages, and I would like to centralize calling the connection by a function or some kind of a global variable -- This way when I need to change the connection string to point the test or production, I can only change it in onle place.

Any ideas for a best practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> I have 2 connection strings in web.config file, one for prod and other for test.

This is an incorrect approach.  What you're trying to do is keep the config file static and change the code between environments, which is opposite of what you should be doing.

In this case you should have *one* connection string in the config file, and two config files (one for each environment), or perhaps a Web.config transform depending on the tooling that you're using.  The idea is that each environment would have a different configuration with the same code, not different code with the same configuration.

So in your config file you might have something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

(Or whatever your actual connection string is.)

Then in your code you'd access it with something like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

Each target environment would (could) have its own connection string in its own config file, but the code shouldn't have to change between environments.

As you're looking to encapsulate the string so you don't have to use that whole `ConfigurationManager` call everywhere, you can certainly do that.  How you do it is up to you.  One approach might be to have a static field on an object somewhere.  Something like this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper
{
    public static string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use the connection string elsewhere in your code you could use this:

```
DatabaseHelper.ConnectionString
```

Which is definitely shorter.  It doesn't really change how the connection string is accessed, it just encapsulated it behind a custom object to reduce the amount of code used on individual lines.

Comment: +1 And I'd recommend downloading the SlowCheetah plugin for VS for this purpose: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

Comment: Yep.  What you need per config file (per environment)...and a bunch of stuff in one single config file.

Comment: Please don't write "voo doo" code.......where you can change on appSetting, and the environment will change.  Keep your .config files clean, sensible, etc, etc and "to standard".  The people who inherit your code will thank you instead of curse you.

Comment: @granadaCoder: What that directed at me or at the OP?  It's not clear what you're getting at.  Isn't the whole point of changing an app setting to account for an environment change?

Comment: The original poster.  Actually, to a guy who wrote a "framework" to make environment switches in app files based on one setting (at a previous job).  The pooper was that you had to define every environment in the same file.  It was a piece of crap.  He was trying to "save time"......and cost people more time getting the environments screwed up over and over....sorry for not being clear.  I was trying to get the OP away from writing "cutesy" code.  Cutesy code......is not inherit'able friendly.

Comment: Sorry, I forget you can't see that I upvoted this response.  I'm in agreement with what you've said here (to David).

Comment: thank you both David and granadacoder (and for others too for the input) -- This is good stuff!  I will start this approach.

Comment: I implemented it, and it worked great, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

A DAL (data access layer) will encapsulate this for you. There are many to choose from: Typed Datasets and TableAdapters being one of the oldest, also Entity Framework, NHibernate, Telerik OpenAccess ... Basically, retrieving the connectionstring is NOT something you should not have to be writing code for yourself.

Also, as @David said, best practice is to have a separately maintained web.config for each configuration, not one that contains both. In our apps, we do have the "other" connectionstrings within web.config but they're commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted David's response.  But will add this to the conversation.

You can put "pointers" to external files in your app.config for web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="ExternalConnectionStrings.config" />
</configuration>
```

Contents of ExternalConnectionStrings.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MainConnectionString"
       connectionString="blah blah blah "
    providerName="yada.yada.yada" />

</connectionStrings>
```

You could have multiple 
ExternalConnectionStrings.config files......based on environment.

```
ExternalConnectionStrings.Development.config
ExternalConnectionStrings.QA.config
ExternalConnectionStrings.Staging.config
ExternalConnectionStrings.Production.config
```

The "trade off" is that you have to manually copy this file (like with a Post Build Event)......but it is "clean".

Then you only have to change one value in your original app.config (or web.config)

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="ExternalConnectionStrings.Production.config" />
</configuration>
```

I'm not saying I do that or suggest that.  But I'd rather you do this....then hack up the original app.config file.

Keep your config files lean and clean................when you're trying to figure out which connection string is being used...you don't want to have to think or parse some voodoo code to figure it out.